# What is the error in this JavaScript rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm aware that there have been numerous amounts of questions exactly like this but I'd like to know as for why this doesn't work. I just started learning js and wanted to make a little Rock Paper Scissors game but I've ran into a problem somewhere it seems. But I can't really seem to find it.

```js
function getUserChoice(userNumber) {
  userNumber = prompt('Rock, Paper, Scissors?')
}

getUserChoice()
const getComputerChoice = () => {

  const randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))

  if (randomNumber === 0) {
    return 'Rock';
  } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return 'Paper';
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    return 'Scissor';
  }
}

function game() {
  if (getUserChoice === getComputerChoice) {
    return 'Tie';
  } else if (getUserChoice === 'Rock' && getComputerChoice === 'Paper') {
    return 'Computer Wins';
  } else if (getUserChoice === 'Paper' && getComputerChoice === 'Scissors') {
    return 'Computer Wins';
  } else if (getUserChoice === 'Scissors' && getComputerChoice === 'Rock') {
    return 'Computer Wins';
  } else if (getComputerChoice === 'Scissors' && getUserChoice === 'Rock') {
    return 'You win';
  } else if (getComputerChoice === 'Scissors' && getUserChoice === 'Rock') {
    return 'You win';
  } else if (getComputerChoice === 'Scissors' && getUserChoice === 'Rock') {
    return 'You win';
  } else {
    return null;
  }

}

document.write(game())
```

```css
/* Basic CSS comment */

body {
  background: rgb(182, 153, 160);
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: rgb(107, 89, 93);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

- In the getUserChoice function, you don't need the userNumber parameter, and you probably want to return the output of the prompt function.
- In the game function, getUserChoice and getComputerChoice are referring to the functions - if you want to refer to their outputs, say `var userChoice = getUserChoice();` and similarly for getComputerChoice, then use those variables in your big if statement.